# Django admin not showing choices for Foreign key field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a small chat app and I have problems making a message in the admin because of the drop down for the `Messagemie` model for field `chat`. Notice in the picture below it does not show the required values associated with the `Conversation` model. The values that the `conversation` field in the `Conversation` model accepts are of the form "number-number", e.g. `5-10`, `11-21` etc. Note that I have created a mechanism not shown below which converts such input formats to strings for non Django admin input (When users start a new conversation).

The `conversation` field is of type `CharField`. I suspect the reason why Django admin form does not show the required values is because of the `field` type, however I am not sure. Also it could be that because Django admin is not converting the input to string thus showing just `Conversation object` in the drop down. Why is Django admin not showing the correct values for the `chat` input field?

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Conversation(models.Model):
    conversation = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    email_1 = models.ForeignKey(Usermie, to_field="email", related_name="email_1_convo")
    email_2 = models.ForeignKey(Usermie, to_field="email", related_name="email_2_convo")



@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Messagemie(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Usermie, to_field="email", related_name="email_sender")
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Usermie, to_field="email", related_name="email_receiver")
    # The username is the sender's username
    sender_username = models.CharField( max_length=50)
    receiver_username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    message = models.TextField()
    chat = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, to_field="conversation", related_name="conversation_chat")
```

Picture showing Messagemie model `chat`field selection in admin

[image]

Picture of input values in `Conversation` model Django admin.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django admin shows the string representation of the object in the dropdown. This could be obtained by calling `str(object)`. You can modify this behaviour by overriding the `__str__` method in your class.

The implementation of the Django base model class (`django.db.models.Model`) has an implementation like below (for python3) -

```
def __str__(self):
    return str('%s object' % self.__class__.__name__)
```

which explains what you see. `self.__class__.__name__` evaluates to `"Conversation"`, hence you end up seeing `"Conversation object"` in the dropdown.

To change this behaviour you can override the `__str__` method to get the desired value returned. One sample implementation is below. You could modify the method easily to do include any logic you want.

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    conversation = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    email_1 = models.ForeignKey(Usermie, to_field="email", 
                               related_name="email_1_convo")
    email_2 = models.ForeignKey(Usermie, to_field="email", 
                                related_name="email_2_convo")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.conversation
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Your answer also answers a next question. I use to wonder why people use `__str__` method, when you can use any method and output whatever you want as a sting simply using `%s`. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help!